In the topos $G$-${\rm Set}$, what role does conjugation in $G$ play?
I apologise if this is an ill-defined question.
Let $G$ be a group.
The topos $G$-${\rm Set}$ has objects $G$-sets (i.e, pairs $(X,\lambda)$ of an action $\lambda$ of $G$ on a set $X$), and arrows action-preserving functions (i.e., $f:(X,\lambda)\to (Y, \mu)$ s.t. $f(\lambda(g, x))=\mu(g,f(x))$ for each $g\in G$).
The Question:

What role, if any, does conjugation play in topos $G$-${\rm Set}$?

Clarification: I'd like a categorial interpretation of the action of conjugation of $G$ on itself, when considered as an object $(G,\operatorname{conj_g})$ of $G$-${\rm Set}$ for arbitrary $g\in G$. Are there generalisations of it to other topoi?
Context:
I don't know.
It's late, and I don't have the background (anymore) to look this stuff up an any detail.  The last time I did any serious topos theory was far too long ago, up until recently, when I decided to pick up Goldblatt's book again; and once I did, thoughts along these lines seem natural to ask because of my postgraduate research in group theory (which I won't go into, given the time).
I want to ask this sooner rather than later as I'm keen and I can see this as a way to springboard into studying the subject more thoroughly.
I have a very rusty, self-taught knowledge of topos theory, having "read" Goldblatt, although only skimming through once I got to Chapter 14.

I don’t see why conjugation action should play any special role. For example, when $G$ is abelian the action is trivial, yet $G$-$\text{Set}$ still has plenty of structures. I’d say the left multiplication action $\lambda$ should play a much larger role: it is a generator of $G$-$\text{Set}$, in fact, an object is a generator iff it is a coproduct of nonzero many copies of $\lambda$; it is the unique atom (up to isomorphism) that admits an epimorphism to every atom; etc.

The conjugation self-action of a group can be considered a special case of the following general construction.
Consider the hom-set functor of a category $\mathcal{C}$, $\textrm{Hom}_\mathcal{C} : \mathcal{C}^\textrm{op} \times \mathcal{C} \to \textbf{Set}$.
If we have any functor $F : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}^\textrm{op} \times \mathcal{C}$, we could compose it to obtain a functor $\mathcal{D} \to \textbf{Set}$, of course.
For example, if $\mathcal{C}^\textrm{iso}$ is the subcategory of isomorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, we have a twisted diagonal functor $\mathcal{C}^\textrm{iso} \to \mathcal{C}^\textrm{op} \times \mathcal{C}$, sending an isomorphism $f$ in $\mathcal{C}$ to the pair $(f^{-1}, f)$, so we obtain a functor $\mathcal{C}^\textrm{iso} \to \textbf{Set}$.
But this is just a sophisticated way of making a simple observation: given an isomorphism $f : X \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ and an endomorphism $e : X \to X$ in $\mathcal{C}$, $f \circ e \circ f^{-1} : Y \to Y$ is another endomorphism in $\mathcal{C}$.
Of course, in the case that $\mathcal{C}$ is a one-object groupoid, this is precisely the conjugation self-action of the corresponding group.
